# Azure Cloud Service - Deploy Error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have been having some difficulty uploading to a Cloud Service (Classic) Worker Role, I week or so ago I could do it but now it gives a error on the VM, the service starts then goes to busy and restarts and loops...

The error that I can extract from Azure is the following:
Failed to extract the meta data. FieldName:Description; ProviderName:Windows Azure Runtime 2.7.0.0

My Azure Tools are at version 2.9.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try to add/update dependentAssembly in the web.config file and see if it helps solving your problem.

Do specify publicKeyToken and version according to your environment.

```
    <dependentAssembly>

      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime"

      <publicKeyToken="xxx" culture="neutral" />

      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="xxxx" newVersion="2.7.0.0" />

    </dependentAssembly>
```

Let us know if it helps solving your issue.